# filter entire data in single column by unselecting multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I am new to excel VBA coding. trying filter entire data by selecting range in SR variable but getting error (run time error 424) at **SR** variable

Also can someone provide further coding. I need to filter out entire data of SR variable by keeping values ("ABC", "DEF") in column D and delete (CTRL Minus) the rest of rows with multiple values other than I mentioned.

Here is starting code:

```
With ActiveSheet
            Dim SR As Range
            LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set SR = Range("A1:AP" & LR)
            SR.Select.AutoFilter

End With
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. We are not a code writing service. You have to make an attempt and provide us your code. We can then help to resolve any issues you have with your code. Also, which line throws the error? the where you are setting **SR** or the one where you setting the filter.. i suspect its the later

Comment: `SR.Select.AutoFilter` looks syntactically wrong.  You shouldn't need the `select` if you've specified the range (`SR`), i.e., `SR.Autofilter`.

Comment: @Cyril.. is there ever a need for `Select` :). Although I did come across a scenario the other day (a question here) where it was actually needed.. how little do i know!

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your code workable, you must use this one:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim SR As Range, LR As Long ', visCells As Range, i As Long
    LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SR = .Range("A1:AP" & LR)
    SR.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="ABC", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="DEF", VisibleDropDown:=False
End With
```

This one will filter the area of your range according to your mentioned criteria.

In order to do what you explained to be needed, I will give you some hints:

If you wish to accomplish the task using the filter, OK. You must create another Range variable which to keep the visible cells, and after that iterate between the initial SR rows and delete the ones not in the visibleCells range.

I would like to mention that it does not need to previously filter the range in order to make this operation. It is enough to iterate between the rows (from the last to the first) and according to your criteria, in column D:D, to delete the rows which do not match.

A workable piece of code, doing what you want:

```
Dim SR As Range, LR As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SR = .Range("A1:AP" & LR)
    SR.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="<>ABC", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>DEF", VisibleDropDown:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      SR.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

In order to better use the VisibleCells approach I made the filtering on the opposite side. Letting visible all the other rows. If you do not use

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    '.........
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

a message asking about all row deletions would appear...

The next code will delete the rows not matching the filtering for more than two criteria.
It works well only if your filtered area starts with the first row. If not, a correction must be done by adding the difference from the first sheet row and the filtered area first row:

```
Dim SR As Range, LR As Long, R As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set SR = .Range("A1:AP" & LR)
        SR.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("ABC", "DEF", "AAA"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        For R = SR.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Rows(R).Hidden Then .Rows(R).Delete
        Next R
    End With
```

In this example it is obviously the first (range("A1:...), but it can be any range from the sheet...

Comment: I think your explanation is mostly correct. Only thing i would add is: using `ActiveSheet` is fraught with danger. I would suggest using early or late binding to the sheet and reference the specific sheet you want to work with

Comment: @Zac: I agree it. I wouldn't use such an approach, neither. I just tried to transform his code in something workable. In fact, according to what I understood about his need, I would do it in a different way... The filtering code is, let us say, a kind of didactic approach just for him, in order to learn something. Finding a code not understanding how it works and what it does is not the most appropriate way of learning, I think...

Comment: Thanks Guys. Yes I do understand that asking for full code is not the appropriate way. Going forward, I will make note of this feedback.

Comment: @SRKAN: I edited my answer and I posted a solution. Not optimized regarding the sheet object binding, which remains a task for you... :-)

Comment: @FaneDuru when I am adding Criteria3, Criteria4, and so on . its throwing me an error "Compile error named argument not found . Cant I add multiple values to filter out?

Comment: @SRKAN:  I am afraid that no more then two criteria are allowed for "Not equal To". But you can set as many criteria you want for equal. In a different way (using an Array). And then iterate between the range rows and delete the hidden ones. I do not know how to post such a code in a comment. In fact, I will edit the answer and complete it with an example.